# Duration Class in Java 8 Date/Time API

Tags: java, datetime

I need some explination why this code does not compile:

```
Duration duration = Duration.from(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

**Error :**

> The method from(TemporalAmount) in the type Duration is not applicable
>   for the arguments (ChronoUnit)

As the the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#from-java.time.temporal.TemporalAmount-) says :

> public static Duration from(TemporalAmount amount) Obtains an instance
>   of Duration from a temporal amount. This obtains a duration based on
>   the specified amount. A TemporalAmount represents an amount of time,
>   which may be date-based or time-based, which this factory extracts to
>   a duration.
>
> The conversion loops around the set of units from the amount and uses
>   the duration of the unit to calculate the total Duration. Only a
>   subset of units are accepted by this method. The unit must either have
>   an exact duration or be ChronoUnit.DAYS which is treated as 24 hours.
>   If any other units are found then an exception is thrown.
>
> Parameters: amount - the temporal amount to convert, not null Returns:
>   the equivalent duration, not null Throws: DateTimeException - if
>   unable to convert to a Duration ArithmeticException - if numeric
>   overflow occurs

I know that there are other ways of creating duration instance but I need some explination why this one does not work.

**EDIT**

When I change like this (Because Period implements TemporalAmount Interface) :

```
Duration d1 = Duration.from(Period.ofDays(1));
```

**It thows this exception :**

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unit must not
>   have an estimated duration

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what amount does `ChronoUnit.DAYS` represent?

Comment: As the doc stated that It's 24 Hours

Comment: Only a subset of units are accepted by this method. The unit must either have an exact duration or be ChronoUnit.DAYS which is treated as 24 hours

Comment: You're misreading. 24 hours is the length of the DAYS unit. You still need to specify how many units.

Comment: "**The unit**" is not an amount - `days` is not an amount but *only* the unit used to express an amount. "*What is the amount you want to sell this car?*" "*I want dollars!*" (1 dollar is 100cents)

Comment: Out of standard `java.time` classes, it only works with `Duration` and `Period`.

Comment: I was just trying it, and with Period.ofDays(1) it creates a Period that has 0 years, 0 months, 1 day, and it won't convert that because it contains years and months, even though the amount is zero. Seems like a bug. I was using Java 1.8.0_181. I wonder if it's fixed in later versions?

Comment: Damn. Doesn't work with JDK 12 or JDK 13, either. :(

Comment: @David Conrad Need to use `Duration.ofDays(1)` which uses `ChronoUnit` instead of `ChronoPeriod`

Comment: Yes, but that's useless. You can only use `Duration.from` on a `Duration`. So to convert to a Duration, first you must have a Duration. Of course, `TemporalAmount` is an interface, so you could create your own class that implements it, and then convert *that* to a Duration.

Answer (score 3):

Your question already mentions that this method expects a **TemporalAmount**. The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAmount.html) for that interface tells us:

> Framework-level interface defining an amount of time, such as "6 hours", "8 days" or "2 years and 3 months".

`ChronoUnit.DAYS` isn't a temporal **amount**. It is simply a temporal unit of measure. But not an amount: `ChronoUnit` implements `TemporalUnit`, not `TemporalAmount`!

In other words: "Hours" isn't an amount. "6 hours is"!

In other words: you can create a `Duration` from a **unit** of measurement. You need to provide something that represents a specific amount of time.

Example:

```
Duration d = Duration.from(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
```

should work (as Duration implements TemporalAmount). In that example, you first define a TemporalAmount of 5 seconds, and then you can build "from" that.

Comment: The docs do say "The unit must either have an exact duration or be ChronoUnit.DAYS which is treated as 24 hours", which makes it seem like it has a special case for `ChronoUnit.DAYS` where it defaults to 24 hours though.

Comment: @Nexevis The **unit** is still a unit. The method expects TemporalAmount, not ...Unit.

Comment: @Nexevis Those are the units in the `TemporalAmount`, which can be either a `Duration` or a `Period`.

Comment: @Nexevis ahh, got it, makes more sense like in "days are not always 24 hours, but `Duration` is implemented to use 24 hours"

Comment: @Carlos Heuberger Yeah exactly, and the docs could probably word it better here.

Answer (score 2):

I believe @GhostCat's answer sufficiently explains how to correctly use `Duration.from` and why `ChronoUnit.DAYs` does not work.  However, I want to clarify the source of your confusion and why you *think* it should work.

This sentence:

> The unit must either have an exact duration or be ChronoUnit.DAYS which is treated as 24 hours.

Is mentioning `ChronoUnit.DAYS` because `ChronoUnit.DAYS` is an *estimation* set to 24 hours, and it is *not* an exact duration like the others.  It does *not* mean you can simply just pass `ChronoUnit.DAYS` and it will act like the `TemporalAmount` of 24 hours.

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#DAYS) from the docs that explains `ChronoUnit.DAYS` is an estimation.

Sentence reworded to be less confusing:

> The unit must have an exact duration except for ChronoUnit.DAYS which is estimated to be 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the confusion here is that the `Period` object (which implements *`TemporalAmount`* interface) can not be used in place of the `Duration` object (which also implements *`TemporalAmount`* interface).

In code:

```
// Below does not work
Duration d1 = Duration.from(Period.ofDays(1));

// This works fine
Duration d1 = Duration.from(Duration.ofHours(24));
```

This is because **`Duration.from`** method would only accept a subset of `ChronoUnit` values, that can be accurately converted to hours:

> Only a subset of units are accepted by this method. The unit must
>   either have an exact duration or be ChronoUnit.DAYS which is treated
>   as 24 hours

From the [Period](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) definition, its value for 1-day (P1D) could be 23 or 24 hours depending on the daylight savings gap. Thus `Period` has no fixed unit value for which 1-day is always 24 hours, and therefore the `UnsupportedTemporalTypeException` is thrown.

From the [TemporalAmount](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAmount.html) interface documentation:

> Period is a date-based implementation, storing years, months and days.
>   Duration is a time-based implementation, storing seconds and
>   nanoseconds, but providing some access using other duration based
>   units such as minutes, hours and fixed 24-hour days.